# Rails Web App UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a rails app and have so far written the html/css for my own front-end by hand.  I am starting to feel like I am "re-inventing the wheel" in that my app looks and feels like a lot of other rails apps out there (tab bar at the top, main content area, secondary navigation area off to the side).

Rather than complete the exercise of re-coding all of the markup structure and UI elements that I will eventually need, I'm wondering if there is a template or plugin or some other rails-y thing out there that I can use.

Google has given me spotty results here (i've found jquery ui and a few other things), so any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If your complaint is that your app looks like other apps, using someone else's premade template isn't going to solve that. You need a designer.

Comment: I'm not complaining that my app looks like others -- I am perfectly happy with that.  I'm just saying that I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, so if there is some codebase out there that I can use it would save me a lot of time.  But yes, if this were a serious commercial app I would definitely want a professional designer. :)

Comment: You could use the blueprint css framework (http://www.blueprintcss.org/) if you are looking for some pre-baked styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question when answering [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170413/approach-to-developing-mobile-application-that-supports-a-web-application/4170686#4170686).

Comment: How does that answer relate to the above question? Maybe you could quote the relevant parts here?

Comment: `First off, if you use a framework like PhoneGap or Sencha Touch or Rhomobile, the big benefit is that you theoretically write the "mobile app" code once and it works across each of the devices supported by the framework. Compared to writing a native app for three platforms, this is a lot less work.`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you feel so inclined, you could also use something like nifty generators https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators with the simple-navigation gem https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation or use an application template like http://everydayrails.com/2011/02/28/rails-3-application-templates.html